# rspec tests always show failure using terminal-notifier-guard

Tags: rspec, guard

Although all my specs show as passing in my terminal, the notification ALWAYS shows they failed.  Its a pretty simple setup, but do i have something misconfigured?  How can i troubleshoot this?

*Gemfile*

```
group :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
end
```

*Guardfile*

```
notification :terminal_notifier
guard :rspec, all_after_pass: true, all_on_start: true do
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was guard was not configured to run rspec using `bundle exec`

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec rspec' do
  ...
end
```